# Downloading openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to download openpyxl to my mac laptop

```
pip install openpyxl
```

I'm getting this error:

error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jdcal.py'

Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/65/3jmvmy9j61j0q_s_3gpmjbx00000gn/T/pip-build-c2EvGS/jdcal/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/65/3jmvmy9j61j0q_s_3gpmjbx00000gn/T/pip-AAo2UU-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/65/3jmvmy9j61j0q_s_3gpmjbx00000gn/T/pip-build-c2EvGS/jdcal/

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have a problem with permissions. Try this:

```
sudo pip install openpyxl
```

Comment: Better still: create a Python virtual environment for your project.

Answer (score 0):

sudo pip3 install openpyxl

Maybe it is getting pip for python 2.7 as default

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PyCharm go to File > Project:pythonProject > Python Interpreter > Click on pluss > Write Openpyxl > Click install

Comment: generally answering a general question with a specific technology is not the best way to answer, unless it is a popular question where the information is in demand for a specific implementation, ide, etc... in this case sudo or virtualenvs are the right answer and its not obvious how the pycharm mention helps.